npm error code EUSAGE when uploading react+vite project to GitHuB
Firstly here is the project repository where the error is occuring: https://github.com/tdM05/tdM05.github.io
I'm trying to deploy my website that I made with React+Vite to GitHub Pages and I keep getting a blank page (that isn't error 404) and ever since I added the deploy.yml file which is in the .github\workflows folder, I would get an error when pushing my commits to github. I added that file because that is what seemed like I should do from what I've read and I was getting a blank page before this.
Right now when I push to github, there is an error when github tries building it during the "install dependencies" phase. Here is the full error:
Run bahmutov/npm-install@v1
running npm-install GitHub Action
trying to restore cached NPM modules
cache key npm-linux-x64-f49928ddd0b76d21d99280ed45df323cea9587a11260ad9b9d67a7a11ca1895408c30700e1d2bbd849607dd72dd268408f86a41aba4ff79a9782a0ddb0a893c5
restore keys [
  'npm-linux-x64-f49928ddd0b76d21d99280ed45df323cea9587a11260ad9b9d67a7a11ca1895408c30700e1d2bbd849607dd72dd268408f86a41aba4ff79a9782a0ddb0a893c5',
  [length]: 1
]
input paths [ '/home/runner/.npm', [length]: 1 ]
npm cache miss
installing NPM dependencies
npm at "/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.4/x64/bin/npm"
/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.4/x64/bin/npm ci
npm error code EUSAGE
npm error
npm error `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm error
npm error Missing: @types/three@0.167.2 from lock file
npm error
npm error Clean install a project
npm error
npm error Usage:
npm error npm ci
npm error
npm error Options:
npm error [--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
npm error [--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm error [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> [--include <prod|dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm error [--strict-peer-deps] [--foreground-scripts] [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit]
npm error [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm error [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm error [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm error
npm error aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm error
npm error Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-08-22T01_20_31_209Z-debug-0.log
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.4/x64/bin/npm' failed with exit code 1
    at ExecState._setResult (/home/runner/work/_actions/bahmutov/npm-install/v1/dist/index.js:6056:25)
    at ExecState.CheckComplete (/home/runner/work/_actions/bahmutov/npm-install/v1/dist/index.js:6039:18)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/bahmutov/npm-install/v1/dist/index.js:5933:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.4/x64/bin/npm' failed with exit code 1

These are the things that I've done so far:

changed vite.config.js to add the property base: "/" because my github repository is called tdM05.github.io. Nothing seemed to happen (which is expected because "/" seems to be the default value).
added this "homepage": "http://tdM05.github.io" to my package.json file. Nothing seemed to change.
Changed "private": true, to "private": false, in my package.json file. Nothing seemed to change.
Ran npm install again. Nothing changed.

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The error is because of a mismatch between your package.json amd package-lock.json files. The error tells that some dependencies in your package-lock.json file do not match the versions in your package.json, specifically @types/three@0.167.2.
Run this command locally to synchronize the two files.
npm install
npm install @types/three@0.167.2

this will update the package-lock.josn file and ensure that both files are in sync.
After that, commit changes to your repo.
git add package-lock.json
git commit -m "blar blar blar"
git push origin main

One more thing to check is your vite.config.js. Check out if it includes the correct base property.
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/', // This should be fine for user.github.io repositories
});

This would work...
